# For which values of d, e, and f are these vectors linearly independent?

Tags: vector-spaces

\left[\begin{pmatrix}e\\0\end{pmatrix}\right],\left[\begin{pmatrix}d\\f\end{pmatrix}\right]

Sorry about the formatting, it's my first time on the site (If anyone knows how to fix it, please tell!) The two vectors should be next to one another.

My thought process for this problem is that in R^2, any two vectors are linearly independent as long as they are not scalar multiples of each other (parallel). So e and d are any two real numbers, and f is any number not equal to zero. Is the problem that simple or am I missing something crucial here?

Comment: Thinking in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

A list of 2 vectors is linearly dependent if and only if the vectors are parallel. You are right.